# Get the highest value in object

Tags: jquery

I have an object like so:

```
var lookup = {
    42: "42", 
    43: "43"
}
```

How can I get the highest value in this object? I am expecting to get `43` because it's the highest number.

Comment: 1) What have you tried? 2) Are you comparing the property names or the values? 3) If it's the values, are you expecting strings to be converted to integers and then compared? 4) Can you use an array instead of an object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments indicate, your question is a bit vague. If you're looking to compare the string values parsed as ints, the following should work based on your object's structure:

```
var myArray = Object.keys(lookup).map(function(current){ 
    return parseInt(current)
});
var max = Math.max.apply(null, myArray)
```

Comment: This does not work if your object contains non-numeric values. The parseInt will return NaN on non-numeric values and the Math.max.apply will return NaN if the array contains a NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:

```
function getMax(dataObj){
var max;
for(var key in dataObj){
     if (dataObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var number = parseFloat(dataObj[key]);
        //max by default is undefined and number could be NaN 
        if(!max && number){ 
            max = number;
        }
        else if(number > max){
            max = number;
        }
    }
}
return max;
}
```

It will loop through an object and get all the properties set on this object (not in the prototype chain), try to convert them to number and then return the max. Note this is not returning the key, but rather the value.

Comment: You can remove the `hasOwnProperty()` check if you use `Object.keys`, save you some typing :)

Comment: Good point @MisterEpic! There is still a compatibility concern with Object.keys if you need to support browsers older than IE9. Check out the article at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys for complete information on Object.keys.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of having a diversity of answers, here's a more functional implementation using lodash's `reduce` and a ternary operator:

```
_.reduce(_.values(lookup), function(max, n){ return n > max ? n : max; });
```